# Do I need to wait for asynchronous method to complete before disposing HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I wonder if this code works as expected (send a string to a web application):

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = Util.CreateHttpClient())
{
    httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("theurl", somestr);
}
```

Since `PostAsJsonAsync` doesn't complete execution immediately, and httpClient is disposed when exiting the block, is the request always sent properly?

Or do I have to wait for the task like this:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = Util.CreateHttpClient())
{
    httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("theurl", somestr).Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the asynchronous API of `HttpClient`, its recommended you `await` these methods:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = Util.CreateHttpClient())
{
    await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("theurl", somestr);
}
```

That way, you ensure completion of the asynchronous method and you make sure `HttpClient` isn't disposed until the request is sent.

If you need a synchronous API, consider looking at `WebClient`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait or keep the client in scope.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?